# Javascript produces wrong numerical answers during data validation

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small javascript routine to check that a user's height is between two limits, and for this I am getting values from two input boxes, one for feet and one for inches. Clicking a button activates the code below.
My routine is as follows:

```
feet = document.getElementById('ft').value;
inches = document.getElementById('in').value;

heighttot = feet+inches/12;
alert(feet); // Right
alert(inches); // Right
alert(heighttot); // Wrong

if(heighttot > 8 || heighttot < 4 )
{
    alert("Please make sure the height is between 4 and 8 feet");
    return;
}
```

I've put some alert boxes to see what is being retrieved. The values for feet and inches are retrieved correctly, but the heighttot is incorrect. Eg if feet=6 and inches=3, heighttot=60.25. I've tried some other test inputs and these are wrong too - eg.feet=7 and inches=6 produces 70.5

Comment: You have to convert the string values of  the input fields into numbers first. One way is `+feet + inches/12`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript equation producing incorrect value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881916/javascript-equation-producing-incorrect-value)

Comment: Or [Reading numbers from inputs with JavaScript always returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7230553/215552)

Comment: you may use the [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for declaring all variables, you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code here:

```
feet = document.getElementById('ft').value;
inches = document.getElementById('in').value;
```

feet and inches are being returned as strings. So when you run this code:

```
heighttot = feet+inches/12;
```

It's actually doing this:

```
1) do the division first, because of order of operations
2) Strings can't be divided, convert inches to a number
3) Divide inches by 12
4) Concat feet and inches. Because feet is a string, convert inches to a string, 
so basically "6" + "0.25"
```

You need to make use of the `parseInt` function to turn your values into integers before doing your math formula.

Comment: parseFloat is a better choice.

Comment: That can be debated, normally it's unusual (at least in my experience) for height fields to allow for float values. But given that there's no reason here not to allow them, you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong because `feet` and `inches` are string.. Try to parse them first

```
feet = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ft').value);
inches = parseFloat(document.getElementById('in').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pull the raw values from the document, they come back as strings. When used with strings, the `+` operator performs string concatenation, so JavaScript is now attempting to combine the two strings into one longer string. When you say `inches/12`, JavaScript infers that you're trying to do math and automatically converts `inches` into a numeric type. So you are now attempting to concatenate the string `6` with the number `0.25` which comes out as `60.25`.

To fix this, you should parse your values into floats before performing mathematical operations on them.

```
feet = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ft').value);
inches = parseFloat(document.getElementById('in').value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to parseInt those so you don't get string values

```
var inches = ( parseInt(feet, 10) *12 ) + parseInt(inches, 10)
```

or

```
var feet = parseInt(feet, 10) + (parseInt(inches, 10) /12 )
```

Comment: That would be to get the answer in inches. The math here is perfectly valid for converting to feet (with a decimal).

Comment: You are right, I didn't pay attention. Updated the answer